# nextJS+new Date() Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML. Warning: Text content did not match

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, material-ui, frontend

I need to get a date in a component. I have built it with React, NextJS and M-UI. I received this error:

> Unhandled Runtime Error
> Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML.
>
> Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "Mon Apr 24 2023 20:52:32 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)" Client: "Mon Apr 24 2023 20:52:33 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)"

```
const UserHeader = () => {

  const alpha = new Date().toString()

  return (
    <Container>
      {alpha}
    </Container>
  )
}
```

I tried to use a common `<div>` and

```
const [alpha, setAlpha] = useState()
```

like [this](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error)
but it didn't help me.

Comment: When React is loaded on the client, it checks the HTML coming down from the server to what it expects to see on client to ensure the HTML hasn't changed. When the `alpha` date is server-side rendered, the rendered date is not matching the client-side rendered date. There are several solutions to this problem, such as: Only render this component on the client (dynamic import the component with no SSR), or only create the date on the client by using `useState` with a `useEffect`, or generate a date on the server (using getServerSideProps) and pass it down as a prop to the `UserHeader` component.

Comment: Depending on how important that date is will determine which solution you'll want to use. For example, if the date needs to be there when the page is server-side rendered for SEO, then the 3rd solution would be suitable. Otherwise, solution 1 or 2 would be better suitable depending on whether or not just the date needs to be client-side only or the entire component has to be client-side only.

Comment: @MattCarlotta thank you! I think 3rd solution will help me

Answer (score 1):

If you know why, understand and really aren't bothered then you can suppress the warning by adding the `suppressHydrationWarning` flag in the containing element.

```
      <span suppressHydrationWarning>
        {alpha}
      </span>
```

The suppression only goes one element deep, it doesn't pass to the children's children, so you'll still receive warnings from further down the tree that may be useful.